# Selection in xslt

Tags: xslt

Hi I have the below xml

```
 <primaryie>
  <content-style font-style="bold">VIRRGIN system 7.204, 7.205</content-style> 
  </primaryie>
```

and by applying the below xslt i'm able to select the number.

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()/text()"/>
```

but in the below case

```
    <primaryie>
  <content-style font-style="bold">VIRRGIN system</content-style> 
  7.204, 7.205 
  </primaryie>
```

how do is select the number? i want something like using xslt:parent of content style.

also i have some cases where both the xmls come together. please let me know how to select the number if both cases are present.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="primaryie/text()">
  <!-- Processing of the two numbers here -->
</xsl:template>
```

**To be sure the template will be selected for execution**, you can have an `xsl:apply-templates` that selects the wanted text node, and that itself is in a template that is selected for execution.

**For example**:

```
<xsl:template match="primaryi">
  <!-- Any necessary processing, including this: -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="content-style">
  <xsl:value-of select="parent::*/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, alternatively

```
<xsl:template match="content-style">
  <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a template design similar to the one below should help :

```
<xsl:template match="primaryie">
    <!-- Do some stuffs here, if needed -->
    <!-- With the node() function you catch elements and text nodes (* just catch elements) -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content-style">
    <!-- Do some stuffs here, if needed -->
    <!-- same way -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Here you got the template which handle the text nodes. It's probably better to add the ancestor predicate to limit its usage to the only text nodes we need to analyze ('cause the xslt processor often has some silent calls to the embedded default template <xsl:template match="text()"/> and override it completely could have some spectacular collaterall damages). -->
<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::primaryie]">
   <!-- Do your strings 'cooking' here -->
</xsl:template>
```